# I am searching for a command for the terminal that will close the GUI and open the CLI

Tags: raspbian-jessie, gui, terminal

I am searching for a command for the terminal that will close the GUI and open the CLI.
I am aware of the key shortcut to get there but am trying to create a shortcut that will run a program from CLI

Comment: [stopping the x-server](http://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/14rlq9/stopping_the_x_server/)

Comment: If by any means you are in fact referring to a shell or a shell script, such as `bash` or `success.sh`, as "CLI", then you can run it at any time you want and need, either from the desktop or in a terminal session, or a `ssh` session.

Your questions is totally unclear as what you really want to achieve, maybe you can rephrase it without acronyms such as `CLI`. Also, what do you mean by "shortcut"?

Answer (score 1):

To end the GUI but remain logged in

```
pkill Xorg
```

To end the GUI and logout (kills all user process, **NEVER run this as root!**)

```
kill -9 -1
```